# Can PCRE test total number of occurrences (of a character class) anywhere in subject?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Given a string that contains a decimal number (in positional base-10 notation):

```php
$numberString = '-123.456789';    // i.e. known to match /^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

I would like to construct a *PCRE* that will test whether *the total number of digits* (across both sides of the radix point) is less than or equal to `N`. So far, I have:

```
/^  [+-]?  ( \d{1,N} | \d[\d.]{0,N} )  $/x
```

But obviously `\d[\d.]{0,N}` also matches `\d{N+1}`, which is incorrect.

An assertion that that ensures the presence of a radix point within that subpattern would help, except assertions are obviously restricted to looking a fixed number of characters forward/back and the number of characters is not known.

Is there a solution to this (deceptively simple) problem?  Obviously I'm aware that it's trivial to solve without regular expressions, but that's not the question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^(?!(?:.*\d){6})[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

You can use `lookahead` for that.Lets suppose we want to say that not more that `5` digits should be there.Or `N = 5`.So we will put a condition to check if we can find `6` digits and fail.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/5

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!  But why is the `*` quantifier necessary on the `.` wildcard?  It seems to me that it should work without, but evidently it does not.

Comment: `.*` it states anywhere in the string.Or else it wont scan the whole string

Comment: Aha, got it.   Thanks again.